# Having some issue with the concept of lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am learning the regex and was trying the lookaround but I am confused with the placement order of these expressions like I am trying the following

```
 b(?!a)
```

the above should mean `b not followed by a`. that is ok now if I place it

```
 (?!a)b
```

this matches b no matter where a comes..

now if I do something like this

```
    ^(?!.*\bMy Links\b).*$
```

in the above the negative lookahead is before the string that consume the characters .. now why is that

so what is the rule in placing the negative lookahead. there is no discussion of the placement in the whole pattern. please explain this ?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html this may help a little (BTW this article has [second part](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html)).

Comment: @Pshemo in the link you mentioned there is positive  lookahead that is in front of the expression that consume characters.. why is it not placed after the character consuming portion..

Comment: Look-around is not causing character consumption. It is zero-width assertion. Maybe [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16763803/1393766) will help you a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the caret `^` to represent the current search position in the string being searched through and in the regex. Take the regular expression `b(?!a)`, and suppose I search through `cafebabe`.  The system tries to find a `b` first.  The first four letters fail, and it reaches the first `b`:

```
cafe^babe    ^b(?!a)
```

The b matches, so it continues in the regular expression:

```
cafeb^abe    b^(?!a)
```

But the negative lookahead fails; the next character is an a.  So, the regex resets and we go to the next place in the string:

```
cafeb^abe    ^b(?!a)
```

This fails, and it continues to

```
cafeba^be    ^b(?!a)
```

The b matches, so

```
cafebab^e    b^(?!a)
```

and the string passes the negative lookahead, so we reach:

```
cafebab^e    b(?!a)^
```

and we pass.

Now, use your second expression.  remember, it's negative lookahead, not negative look behind.

```
^cafebabe    ^(?!a)b
```

The c passes, so it continues to

```
^cafebabe    (?!a)^b
```

which fails.

resetting the regex and advancing the string gives:

```
c^afebabe    ^(?!a)b
```

which fails since because the negative lookahead fails.

The next two fail just as the first one failed, leaving:

```
cafe^babe    ^(?!a)b
```

The negative lookahead succeeds, so we continue to

```
cafe^babe    (?!a)^b
```

which succeeds.  Suppose you went further.  The next letter fails, just as the second one did:

```
cafeb^abe    ^(?!a)b
```

After that comes

```
cafeba^be    ^(?!a)b
```

That a precedes the current place does not matter at all.  b satisfies the negative look ahead, so we go to

```
cafeba^be    (?!a)^b
```

and this passes.  The final alternative fails.

## Added

In your third example, the negative lookahead is at the very beginning, but starts with a `.*`.  So, it passes if there is no sequence of any characters followed by a word boundary, followed by `My Links` followed by a word boundary.  If that passes, then it proceeds to consume the *entire string* while capturing nothing.  So, it's equivalent to *Does this string contain `My Links` surrounded by word boundaries*?  Simply trying to find `\bMy Links\b` and failing will be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps too much to understand it somehow. The third example in my question will to lengthy to explain but I need a little on that too.. as far as I guess it reads like "match string containing MY Links at word boundaries" but if it matches then from your explaination i guess it should never move the control to the next part.. am i correct?

Comment: That's why it's called lookahead.  It looks, but never advances.

Answer (score 1):

You must know that look-around is "zero-width" like `^`, `$` or `\b` which means it only represents **place of cursor** not "character". In look-around mechanism it is done simply by making regex engine remember position of cursor before entering look-around part, and after that part cursor will be reset to this previously remembered position.

Now if you want to check if some letter (in your case `b`) has not other letter (in your case `a`) after it you need to write it as `b(?!a)`. This will make regex first find `b` (which will set cursor after `b`) and then test letter after it `a`.

If you will write it as `(?!a)b` regex for each cursor position (lets say that it is before `b`) will do look-ahead test (so it will temporary move cursor to next positon, read character before it and check if it is not `a`. Since cursor was previously before `b` it will accept that `b` is not `a` and move cursor back before `b`. Now after look-ahead test regex engine will move to next part of tegex pattern (it will check if next character is `b`) and since cursor was before `b` match will be found.

So in case of `(?!a)b` every `b` will be OK, since there is no way that `b` can be `a`

Comment: Thanks.. I was trying this example `\b\w+\b(?!\bcat\b)` that i suppose to reject words that is followed by cat but that does not seem to work ..

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls I don't see any whitespaces in your regex so `\b` may have problem with finding word boundaries. Maybe include `\s` to your look-ahead and try this way `\b\w+\b(?!\s*\bcat\b)`.

Comment: nice!!! Thanks .. I need little more help because the online material is not making me clear.. So If I can talk to you directly on some channel? here posting discussion question may not be allowed..

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls Sorry, not today. It is 23.42 at my place and I need to go sleep soon. But there are lot of people here. If you will ask specific question with simple example I am sure you will get some help.